# Youtube API fails to create two simultaneous bindings of livestreams and livebroadcasts (1 to 1)

Tags: node.js, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-nodejs-client, youtube-livestreaming-api

First I'll explain how it works to create live streamings using the Youtube API then Second I'll explain the use case Third I'll paste my code snippet.

**How it works :**

Basically you need to create a livebroadcast (`youtube.liveBroadcasts.insert`) and get the **livebroadcast id** (1)
then create a livestream (`youtube.liveStreams.insert`) and get the **livestream id** from it (2) once you have both you need to **bind** the livestream to the livebroadcast (`youtube.liveBroadcasts.bind`) :

the result of the binding contains basically the stream URL.

**The Use case**:

Basically it's a livestreaming api : the user register one or multiple youtube accounts, I run the below code to create livestreams and fetch the rtmp urls so I can stream simultaneously on multiple youtube channels.

**the code** :

```
oauth2Client.setCredentials({
    access_token: youtube_tokens.access_token,
    refresh_token: youtube_tokens.refresh_token,
    expiry_date: true
});

var youtube_broadcasts_body = {
    snippet: {
        //     "scheduledEndTime": "2016-11-23T20:00:00.0+08",
        "scheduledStartTime": start_date,
        "title": target.stream_title
    },
    status: {
        "privacyStatus": "private"
    },
    contentDetails: {
        "projection": youtubeProjection
    }
}
var youtube_livebroadcast_params = {
    part: "id,snippet,status, contentDetails",
    resource: youtube_broadcasts_body
}
var youtube_stream_body = {
    snippet: {
        "title": target.stream_title
    },
    cdn: {
        "ingestionType": "rtmp",
        "frameRate": "30fps",
        "resolution": target.youtube_resolution
    }
}
var youtube_stream_params = {
    part: "id,snippet,cdn,status",
    resource: youtube_stream_body
}
var youtube = google.youtube({ version: 'v3', auth: oauth2Client });

youtube.liveBroadcasts.insert(youtube_livebroadcast_params, function(err, res) {
    if (err) {
        logger.fatal(err)
        return callback(err)
    }
    target.broadcast = res
    target.status = "livebroadcast_event_created"
    var broadcast_id = res.id

    youtube.liveStreams.insert(youtube_stream_params, function(err, res) {
        if (err) {
            logger.fatal(err)
            return callback(err)
        }
        var stream_id = res.id
        res.broadcast_id = broadcast_id
        target.stream = res
        target.status = "livestream_created"
        var youtube_livebroadcast_bind_params = {
            part: "id,contentDetails",
            streamId: stream_id,
            id: broadcast_id
        }

        youtube.liveBroadcasts.bind(youtube_livebroadcast_bind_params, function(err, res) {
            if (err) return callback(err)
            target.status = "livebroadcast_bound_to_livestream"
            target.ingest_url = target.stream.cdn.ingestionInfo.ingestionAddress + "/" + target.stream.cdn.ingestionInfo.streamName
            target._id = broadcast_id
            return callback(null, target)
        })
    })
})
```

What happening is that when I call this code twice (in a for loop) the Youtube api returns an error : **Livebroadcast not found** As if there is a race condition somewhere causing to create 1 single and all the others fails.
One dirty workaround that I had to do is to add a timeout (every 2 seconds) but if more than one user will use "my API" this will cause the whole thing to fail.

Now I'm thinking about creating a queue that will manage the creation of the youtube livestreams. Wondering if anyone had the issue ...

Comment: Do you have a larger codebase I can look at? I'm intersted more context to help diagnose.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this code is wrapped in a function that is using an outer **oauth2Client**  object initialized outside it :

```
 const oauth2Client = new OAuth2( // initialize the object outside is wrong 
      YOUTUBE_CLIENT_ID,          // when you wanna use new tokens 
      YOUTUBE_CLIENT_SECRET,      // inside the function.
      YOUTUBE_REDIRECT_URL
 );

var createLiveEvent = function(target, callback) {

    var youtubeDestination = target.destination
    var youtube_tokens = youtubeDestination.user_data;

    oauth2Client.setCredentials({
        access_token: youtube_tokens.access_token,    //tokens got from oauth2 authentication
        refresh_token: youtube_tokens.refresh_token,
        expiry_date: true
    });


    var youtube = google.youtube({
        version: 'v3',
        auth: oauth2Client
    });

    logger.debug("Youtube: Creating event on Channel ")
    ....
    ....

})
```

The solution is actually to use a different **oauth2Client** object **inside** the function for every different access_token/refresh_token :

```
var createLiveEvent = function(target, callback) {
    let oauth2Client = new OAuth2(
        YOUTUBE_CLIENT_ID,
        YOUTUBE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        YOUTUBE_REDIRECT_URL
    );


    var youtubeDestination = target.destination
    var youtube_tokens = youtubeDestination.user_data;

    oauth2Client.setCredentials({
        access_token: youtube_tokens.access_token,
        refresh_token: youtube_tokens.refresh_token,
        expiry_date: true
    });

    ....
    ....
});
```